# Model Validation Messages Rails 4 form errors not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form which allows a user to invite multiple people via adding emails in a comma separated list. In my "Participant" model, I have a call to validate the uniqueness of the email entered (scoped by "project_id").   In the model validation, it gives a place to explain the error (message), but I can't get that error to show up on my form if the validation fails. 
If a user enters the email of a person that has already been added, how can I get the errors message to render?

participant.rb

```
class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false, scope: :project_id, message: "Looks like you\'ve already added this person."} 
end
```

participant_controller.rb

```
def new_participant
  @new_participants = Participant.new
  @participants = Participant.where(project_id: @project.id).includes(:user)
  @template = Template.find(@project.template_id)
  @address = Address.where(project_id: @project.id).first
  @food = ProjectRestriction.where(project_id: @project.id)
end

def add_participant
 @added_by = User.find(current_user.id)
 @new_participants = params[:new_participants][:email].split(/,\s*/)
 @new_participants.each do |t|
  newpart = Participant.new(:email => t, :project_id => @project.id, :level => 4, 
          :participant_cat_id => 2,  :last_updated_by => current_user.id, :added_by => current_user.id, :status => 'unseen')
      respond_to do |format|
              if newpart.save
                ProjectMailer.notify_recipient(newpart, @project, @added_by, @participant_invite ).deliver_later
                self.response_body = nil
                redirect_to participants_path(p: @project.id, w: 'recipient')
              else
                format.html { redirect_to new_participant_path(p: @project.id)}
                format.json { render json: @new_participants.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
              end
        end
    end
end
```

form

```
    <%= form_for :new_participants, url: add_participant_path( :p => @project.id), html: { :multipart => true, :class=> "form-horizontal", id: "basicForm" } do |f| %> 

    <% if @new_participants.errors.any? %>

   <h2>OOPS!</h2>
      <ul>

      <%  @new_participants.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul></div>
<% end %>

 <div class="form-group ">
 <label class="form-label dk-aqua"> Email: <span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
 <%=    f.text_field :email, :autofocus => true, :required => true, :maxlength => 55, :placeholder => 'Email(s)', :class => 'form-control'  %>
 </div>

<%= f.submit 'INVITE',  :class => 'btn btn-aqua btn-lg btn-block', 
           :style => 'margin-bottom:-5px' %>  
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main issues are:

1. you are creating a respond block for each email in the request. 1 request = 1 response.
2. The objects in stored in memory in `@new_participants` are not actually saved.
3. In your views your are treating `@new_participants` as if it where a single resource.

**Pay attention to pluralization when naming routes, variables and actions.**

---

```
def add_participants
    @added_by = User.find(current_user.id)
    @new_participants = params[:new_participants][:email].split(/,\s*/)

    @new_participants.map do |email|
        newpart = Participant.new(
                    :email => email, 
                    :project_id => @project.id, 
                    :level => 4, 
                    :participant_cat_id => 2,  
                    :last_updated_by => current_user.id, 
                    :added_by => current_user.id, 
                    :status => 'unseen'
        )
        if newpart.save
            ProjectMailer.notify_recipient(newpart, @project, @added_by, @participant_invite ).deliver_later
        end
        new_part
    end

    @invalid = @new_participants.reject(&:valid?)

    if @invalid.any?
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to new_participant_path(p: @project.id)}
          format.json { render json: @new_participants.map(&:errors), status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    else 
        respond_to do |format|
            redirect_to participants_path(p: @project.id, w: 'recipient')
        end
    end
end
```

---

```
<ul>
<% @new_participants.each |p| %> 
    <% p.errors.messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end if p.errors.any? %>
<% end %>
</ul>
```